# Calculating standard error of predicted probabilities using stats model's logit -Pythin

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am running logit regression:

```
Y = df_filtered["Democracy"] #setting dependent variable
X = df_filtered.drop(["Democracy"], 1) #setting independent variables
X = sm.add_constant(X.astype(float))
X = X.dropna() #removing missing values from explanatory variables
Y = Y[X.index] #removing corresponding values from dependent variable

model = sm.Logit(Y, X)
logit_model = model.fit()
print(logit_model.summary())
```

and predicting probability of X for a new observation:

```
new_observation = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(private_mc_dict, orient='index').T #swaps the rows and columns of a DataFrame.

# add a constant to the dataframe, so it can be used with the fitted logistic regression model
new_observation = sm.add_constant(new_observation)
new_observation = new_observation.reindex(columns=X.columns, fill_value=1)

private_mc_prob = logit_model.predict(new_observation)
print("P for private middle clas: ", private_mc_prob)
```

I also need to calculate the standard error of the prediction, but I have not found how to do that. Can someone help?

Comment: In statsmodels 0.13 you can use GLM with binomial family in place of Logit. GLM results has get_prediction method with standard errors and confidence interval for predicted mean. In upcoming 0.14 release, Logit, Probit and the discrete count models also have a `get_prediction` method.